# How to add advance custom field just after the post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, genesis

I am using Genesis framework and I want to add advance custom field just after the post, I did some code but the field is not coming just after the post.

Here is the code:

```
add_action('genesis_entry_content', 'add_content_after_content');
function add_content_after_content() {
    echo '<div class="tips-text-image">';
    echo '<img src="' . get_field('image') . '">';
    echo the_field('text');
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: You will need to get the post id and pass it to the get_field function. `echo '<img src="' . get_field('image', $post_id) . '">';` Ref: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: @David.J Advance custom field data is showing but i want it to just after my post.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of where it is being displayed? It maybe worth adding in your code from single.php so we can reference it. Can you not add the function at the bottom of single.php?

Comment: @David.J Screenshot of page http://imgur.com/Nvtrnx7

Comment: You would need to add this towards the end of single.php or content.php depending on how your theme is setup, I would need to see the file contents though.

Comment: @David.J I added above function in functions.php, single.php have only written genesis();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73748/discussion-between-novice-and-david-j).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this http://genesistutorials.com/visual-hook-guide/ or install this plugins on your site https://wordpress.org/plugins/genesis-visual-hook-guide/

You can add extra content after content on this hooks.

```
add_action('genesis_entry_footer', 'after_new_content');
add_action('genesis_after_entry', 'after_new_content');
add_action('genesis_after_endwhile', 'after_new_content');
add_action('genesis_after_loop', 'after_new_content');
add_action('genesis_after_content', 'after_new_content');
add_action('genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap', 'after_new_content');
function after_new_content(){ echo 'new content'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your fields as variable first, then use the variables in the echo's.  Many times when you directly grab the data it places it outside of the container, thus pushing it to the top.  Try this:

```
 add_action('genesis_entry_content', 'add_content_after_content');
 function add_content_after_content() {
     $image = get_field('image');
     $theText = get_field('text');
     echo '<div class="tips-text-image">';
     echo '<img src="' . $image . '">';
     echo $theText;
     echo '</div>';
 }
```